# How to make layers deep decision tree with showing/hiding HTML divs?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to make an HTML page consisting of decision trees depending on the option selected during dropdown. I could only make it one layer deep with a Yes or a No, but couldn't proceed with a Yes/No after a first Yes or a Yes/No after a first No. Is there something in the script I have to change to make it applicable or is it in the naming of the HTML tag?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.myDiv").hide();
  $("div.myDiv2").hide();
  
  $('#myselection').on('change', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    $("div.myDiv").hide();
    $("#show" + value).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Is the forest land expected to be converted to non-forest land in the baseline case, or expected to be subject to authorized conversion to a managed tree plantation in the baseline case?
  <select id="myselection">
    <option>Select Option</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="showYes" class="myDiv">
  Is the land legally authorized and documented to be converted to non-forest or a managed tree plantation?
  <select id="myselection">
    <option>Select Option</option>
    <option value="YesYes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="showNo" class="myDiv">
  Is the forest in the baseline expected to degrade by fuelwood extraction or charcoal production?
  <select id="myselection">
    <option>Select Option</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="showYesYes" class="myDiv2">
  Avoiding planned deforestation/planned degradation
</div>

<div id="showYesNo" class="myDiv2">
  Avoiding unplanned deforestation
</div>

<div id="showNoYes" class="myDiv2">
  Avoiding forest degradation
</div>

<div id="showNoNo" class="myDiv2">
  Proposed project cannot be done
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:** IDs must be unique, therefor you should change the ID `myselection` that you have 3 times in your code (maybe in a class):

```html
<select class="myselection">
```

```js
$('.myselection').on('change', function() {...});
```

---

You could solve your issue by combining the ID of the parent DIV and the value of the select with the `attr()` function and the `parents()` function, which accepts a selector as argument:

```js
var value = $(this).val();
var parent_id = "#" + $(this).parents('div').attr('id');

$(parent_id + value).show();
```

To get this to work, you need to give the first div also such an ID:

```html
<div id="show">Is the forest land expected...
```

and change the value of the `Yes` option of the second select from `YesYes` to `Yes`...

To control, which layer should be hidden, you could use a data attribute (maybe `data-target`), which you can use as selector for the `hide()` function:

```html
<div id="show" data-hide=".myDiv, .myDiv2">Is the forest land expected...
```

```js
var hide_selector= $(this).parents('div').data('hide');
        
$(hide_selector).hide();
```

**Working example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".myDiv").hide();
  $(".myDiv2").hide();
  
  $('.myselection').on('change', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var parent_id = '#' + $(this).parents('div').attr('id');
    var hide_selector = $(this).parents('div').data('hide');
    
    $(hide_selector).hide();
    $(parent_id + value).show();
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="show" data-hide=".myDiv, .myDiv2">Is the forest land expected to be converted to non-forest land in the baseline case, or expected to be subject to authorized conversion to a managed tree plantation in the baseline case?
  <select class="myselection">
    <option>Select Option</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="showYes" class="myDiv" data-hide=".myDiv2">
  Is the land legally authorized and documented to be converted to non-forest or a managed tree plantation?
  <select class="myselection">
    <option>Select Option</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="showNo" class="myDiv" data-hide=".myDiv2">
  Is the forest in the baseline expected to degrade by fuelwood extraction or charcoal production?
  <select class="myselection">
    <option>Select Option</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="showYesYes" class="myDiv2">
  Avoiding planned deforestation/planned degradation
</div>

<div id="showYesNo" class="myDiv2">
  Avoiding unplanned deforestation
</div>

<div id="showNoYes" class="myDiv2">
  Avoiding forest degradation
</div>

<div id="showNoNo" class="myDiv2">
  Proposed project cannot be done
</div>
```

Comment: Hi biberman, thanks for the revisions! I kinda get the logic. I ran the codes you provided and it went ok as it went all the way to the third layer where decisions were given. Some problems though, as soon as the second layer options were selected to give the answers, the second layer disappears. Is there a way to keep it on?

Secondly, once the selections change to produce a different output, the old output stays on the page. How to hide that because $("div.myDiv2").hide(); doesnt work.

Thanks again!

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
        $("div.myDiv").hide();
        $("div.myDiv2").hide();
        
        $('.myselection').on('change', function() {
            var value = $(this).val();
            var parent_selector = $(this).parents('div').attr('id');

            $("#" + value).show();
            $("#" + parent_selector + value).show();
        });
    });

The code works, only on the first run (after first selection, second prompt appears. after second selection, answer appears without removing the second prompt). But if first selection changed, it adds to prior.